# YQL query with open data tables crashes Titanium mobile app

Tags: titanium, yql

I'm running into an issue with Titanium's Titanium.Yahoo.yql method on iPhone. I'm trying to execute a query which uses an open data table that I've built but unfortunately, it's causing the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert
>   nil value (key: data)'

Here's the query:

```
USE touchlocal_businesses.xml AS touchlocal.businesses; SELECT * FROM touchlocal.businesses WHERE business="plumbers" AND location="brighton" AND apikey="xxx";
```

I've confirmed that the query does in fact return results in the YQL console. I've also tried another query, one that doesn't use an ODT, in my app and that works OK.

My best guess is that it's something to do with this type of query requiring an HTTPS connection.

Has anyone else run into this? Any help would be appreciated :)

Cheers, Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug that was fixed in 1.8.0.1:

http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6005